# Exclude jar from java jre

Tags: java

I am having an issue with deploying spring boot war due to jar duplicate.
The root issue is that I had to add a jar manually to java ext folder because I need it in other solutions.
And now this jar is also existing in the war I am deploying so is there any way to exclude this jar from being loaded from jre and instead be loaded from my dependencies only ?

Comment: Putting things in `lib/ext` was (almost) always the wrong solution. In recent Java versions, it isn't even possible anymore. So, remove the lib from `lib/ext`, and fix the problem with the applications that do need it, or define the dependency to your Spring Boot app as a "provided" dependency, so it isn't included in the WAR. Both Maven and Gradle provide options for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remove it from ext as I need it for older services, and the version for the lib is older than the one I am using in the new service so, this won't be working for me

Comment: Then you need to use a separate JRE installations to run the older and the newer applications.